# How can I find with the Create React App network URL when warnings are displayed

Tags: reactjs, networking, localhost

So, I have my CRA served at `localhost:3000`, but once I start working on it, the ESLINT and the Prettier warnings are displayed, and the network URL is hidden. How can I find out what the local network URL is, so I can open it on other devices?

[image: terminal output]

Answer (score 0):

`If you using VS Code then hover over it, and disable it that particular line`

or

Just add `// eslint-disable-next-line` to the line above warning is shown

and then serve that app again...

After getting network url you can just remove that comments.

Comment: But, while I’m developing, the warnings are waay to many to disable eslint on each line. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only way I worked round it was:

1. Create a brand new React app with CRA
2. Run the new app and copy the network address (as it won't have ESLINT warnings)
3. Stop the new app server
4. Run your original app (the one with the warnings)
5. Paste the network IP from the demo app
6. You can now run your ESLINT warnings app with a network IP

Answer (score 0):

use `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` in terminal, you will find your ip, then use `http://<your-ip>:<your-project-running-port>`.

e.g. `http://192.168.100.7:3000`